# how to apply optical flow vector to detected circle only

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, opticalflow

I am working on traffic sign detection project. Circular traffic sign has been detected, now i want to calculate optical flow vector to traffic sign only but not whole image. 
I could find radius of detected circle but not sure how to use this to create a circular mask **IplImage** to provide to **"cvGoodFeatureToTrack"** and **"cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK()"**

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: please **do not** use IplImage* or any of the deprecated cv* functions, but the c++ api (cv::Mat, etc.)

Comment: I agree but project is developed in deprecated cv* function since beginning.
So not possible to switch now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the center and radius of the traffic sign, i.e.:

```
cv::Point center(200, 300);
int radius = 50;
```

The region of interest, where [`goodFeaturesToTrack`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#goodfeaturestotrack) will work can be controled by a `CV_8UC1` mask which has the same size as the input image:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(grayFrame.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::circle(mask, center, radius, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);
```

Finally call the function with our new mask filled with 255s according to the traffic sign:

```
cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(grayFrame, corners, 100, 0.01, 10, mask);
```